# Discontinuous lines in StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to plot a vector field using the function `StreamPlot`:

```
StreamPlot[{0, rho (1 - rho) - j}, {j, 0, 1/3}, {rho, 0, 1},
 Frame -> None, StreamPoints -> 100, StreamScale -> {0.3},
 StreamStyle -> Green, StreamMarkers -> "PinDart"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This vector field is essentially made of vertical lines. My problem is that Mathematica only seems to draw parts of these lines, while I would like them to be continuous and span the entire range on the vertical axis.

I have tried to use several graphical options for this command, but nothing seems to work. Any idea?

Comment: Are you certain they are straight vertical lines?  Some of the vectors are `{0,0}` so they will not be drawn.  Have a look at `ContourPlot[rho (1 - rho) - j, {j, 0, 1/3}, {rho, 0, 1}]` to see that the varying values in the vertical plane.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because zero length vectors are not drawn on `StreamPlot`.

Comment: tried `StreamScale -> Full`?

Comment: I am aware that there are points where the flow is (0,0), and I do not expect Mathematica to produce a plot for them (I apologize if this was not clear before). What I would expect is for the lines to be defined above/below these points, instead of on one side only. I have tried StreamScale->Full, but it does not work :/

Comment: Show an image of what you get.  I get stream lines throughout the plotting domain: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wJWnQ.png

Comment: I get the exact same image, the problem is that as long as j<=1/4 the vertical lines are "interrupted" as soon as they meet the points where the flow is (0,0), whereas I would like to have vertical lines which only have one "hole" at these points, but are otherwise always defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define explicit starting points for streamlines.

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{{j, 1/2}, {j, 0}, {j, 1}}, {j, 0, 1/3, 1/30}], 1];

sp = StreamPlot[{0, rho (1 - rho) - j}, {j, 0, 1/3}, {rho, 0, 1}, 
       StreamPoints -> pts, StreamScale -> {0.3}, StreamStyle -> Green];

cp = ContourPlot[0 == rho (1 - rho) - j, {j, 0, 1/3}, {rho, 0, 1}];

Show[cp, sp]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, thank you! :)